# Define hover attributes with DOM elements

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm working on a Chrome extension which displays a dynamically loaded popup. User can change settings to choose its color. My issue is that I would like to change some :hover attributes of popup's elements, but I don't find how.

My current code:

```
var myDiv = document.createElement('a');
myDiv.style.background = myIcon;
myDiv.style.backgroundImage = myURL;
```

What I would like to add (not working code atm):

```
myDiv.hover.style.backgroundColor = myColor;
```

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set styles for pseudoclasses with JavaScript. Instead, you must define them with CSS. You can use JavaScript to dynamically add CSS to a page, though:

```
var style = document.createElement("style");
style.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode("some-selector:hover { /*...*/ }")
);
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
```

...or similar.

Here's an example adding an element with class `foo` to a document, along with dynamically-defined styles for it:

```js
var foo = document.createElement("div");
foo.className = "foo";
foo.innerHTML = "This is foo, hover me";
document.body.appendChild(foo);

var style = document.createElement("style");
// Pick a color at random
var color = ["red", "blue", "green"][Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
style.appendChild(
    document.createTextNode(
          ".foo:hover { background-color: " + color + " }")
);
document.querySelector("head").appendChild(style);
```

Comment: Ok thank you, but need to create several "myDiv" with different hover styles. Do you think I could add something like ' .* ' after each selector in the static css file, and define different hover styles by differentiating selector like that: var myDiv = document.createElement('a.id'); ?

Comment: @Nucktrooper: If you're using a CSS file (e.g., the content of the styles isn't dynamic) anyway, just give the various elements something to identify them (a class, an ID if they're unique) and use that to trigger the styling.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using CSS to define the base (size, icons, ..) of elements, and DOM to define different attributes (colors,...).